# Import and read more than one .dat file using (For) loop and importdata

Tags: matlab, for-loop

How I can import using `importdata` and then read more than one .dat file using a `for` loop?

For example I have ten .dat files in one folder (lets say folder name is Result) and files are (v1.dat,v2.dat,.......,v10.dat)(files are different names)

In my program I want to have loop to import and read these files then calculate velocity.

For first time I want to import v1.dat to get the result then for second time I want to import v2.dat to get second result and so one for ten times.

Comment: This question use importdata . it is not same question

Comment: The answers from the linked question will resolve this. All you need to do is replace `fopen` with `importdata`.

Comment: Duplicate is valid.  Voted to close.